# How to edit migration tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, migrate

I created my model and then filled my migration file `db/migration/234802843208_create_XXXXX_rb`with the following:

```
class CreateXXXXX < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :XXXXX do |t|

                t.string  :gender
        t.date    :date_of_birth
        t.string  :Marital_status
        t.string  :Spouses_name
```

I ran rake db:migrate.

Now I want to edit the table. I want to change Marital_status to take a Boolean datatype rather than a string. Is there a proper way to do this? Can I just go in an edit the table and re-run rake db:migrate ? Would you recommend I rollback, edit, then re-migrate or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
rake db:rollback
```

or

```
rake db:migrate:down
```

and then open your migration file and update the changes

```
class CreateXXXXX < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :XXXXX do |t|

        t.string  :gender
        t.date    :date_of_birth
        t.boolean  :Marital_status
        t.string  :Spouses_name

  end
```

and do `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:migrate:up`

Answer (score 0):

What seems handy to me on these cases is to edit the file and then run a

```
rake db:migrate:redo
```

If that is not possible I would suggest a rollback and then migrate after you update the migration class.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another migration, and edit that field.

```
rails g migration edit_xxxx_marital_status
```

which creates a migration file. And add the following content to it.

```
class EditXXXXMaritalStatus < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def up
    change_column XXXXX. :Marital_status, :boolean, default: false # if you waNT TO add any default value
 end

 def down
   change_column :XXXXX, :Marital_status, :string 
 end
end
```

Comment: This seems more complicated than the other answers. What advantages does this method have?

Comment: If you have to do the same in the production and live data are there in the table, then by doing rollback you will loose the data.